# Is silverlight dead ? aka should ppl stick to HTML 5 for RIA?

Tags: silverlight, html

It seems to be that Silverlight is rarely mentioned or seen anywhere on the net these days. Even DotNetRocks rarely give any serious time to discussing this technology other than saying they "love" it.

Comment: Considering that half the world probably doesn't have an HTML 5 enabled browser, it's probably not a good idea to stick to HTML 5.

Comment: Not even close to dead. From Dec 2010: http://www.silverlight.net/news/events/firestarter/

Comment: If SO is any indication, there are like 3 times as many Silverlight questions as HTML5 questions.

Comment: @Gabe not quite that means a lot of ppl are confused and probably asking the same q over and over again.

Comment: @Gabe they will eventually get a html5 browser. Plz tell me a major site that uses silverlight - i have yet to see one and plz dont tell me toyota etc. tell me a real site like google maps, wikipedia, ebay etc.

Comment: @mp  People using HTML5 doesn't ask the same questions again?

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight seems to be shifting to a development platform for Microsoft's other products.  It currently is a major part of Windows Phone 7, and is rumored to be coming to the XBox360.